Help identify this movie about college student robber?
I've seen this movie a couple years ago. The main character is a student, as well as a robber, and gets caught... Following some events he joins a college. 
On one of his courses (psychology?) he has a female teacher, who he doesn't like at first, but then they develop a relationship. There's a scene where she takes him to a strip club. There's another scene, where the student meets his girlfriend at an art museum, but runs off from her to a back room to find the teacher. 
Towards the end the teacher tells him to steal an expensive art picture, but in reality she frames him for the murder of her rich husband (or so I remember). Finally the student finds her at an airport, which leads to her arrest by the police. 

Sounds like Xtra Credit from 2009 about a 19-year-old burglar who attends a college after he's caught, where he falls in love with an art student but also with a manipulative sociology professor who tricks him into breaking into her rich husband's house to frame the student for his murder (she also lures him to a strip club at some point). The plot seems to contain a ton of twists. There's a short clip in this site.
